# Are finitely generated solvable groups polycyclic?

Tags: solvable-groups

I know that a polycyclic group is a finitely generated solvable group.
Also I know that, in the case of finite groups, the two notions: polycyclic group and solvable group are equivalent. But I can not  find an example of a finitely generated solvable group which is not polycyclic.

Comment: Yes! Many thanks!